# JSON file type missing in Add new item of Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I need to add a JSON file to add the test data. But JSON file type is missing in Add new item tab.
I have used Console application (.NET Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it in `Add New Item` -> `Web` -> `Markup` -> `JSON File`

[image]

Or easiest way is to search it in Search box.

[image]

---

If web option is not visible on your machine that means while installation you have not selected option `ASP.NET and web development tool`.

Modify your installation and install web development tool on your machine.

If you want quick solution then, in add new item window change extension of `.cs` file to `.json` it will create json file for you

Comment: Web option itself is not available. Also json not available in search results too.

Comment: Modified installation. JSON file type available now